# Revoking third party cookies

Tags: cookies

Can anyone please confirm the industry-standard approach to removing third-party cookies (using JavaScript) in the event that a user has initially granted consent but later revoked it?

**Example situation**

- User visits website and absentmindedly agrees to all cookies
- 3rd party cookies get set as a result
- some time later they realise what they've done and opt to revoke consent

At this point, how can you remove cookies from third-party vendors that have already been set?

All of the solutions I've seen only seem to describe removal of first-party cookies or initially preventing cookies until consent has been granted